# Achieving Isolation for Specific Rows in Database C#

Tags: c#, transactions, locking

I have an application which issues letters to users in sequential order. This is the database structure

```
-------------------
UserID  LastIssued
-------------------
User1   2
User2   3
User3   0
User4   3
--------------------
```

Admin users are able to issue letters (increment the number) to user. There are multiple admins who are able to login parallelly in the system.

This is the function which is used to issue letters

```
private void issueNewLetterToUser(String userid)
{
    int lastIssued;
    lastIssued = getLastIssuedForUserID(userid);
    //CHECKPPOINT1
    lastIssued++;
    updateLastIssuedForUserID(userid);
}
```

While the execution is at checkpoint 1 in the code, suppose another admin calls the same function for the same user, next letter will be issued by two admins. I want to prevent this. Also, if the function call is for some other user, the execution should be allowed because the database rows are independent.

How can I achieve this?
(The question is specific to C# syntax, but still applicable to all languages)

Comment: *"suppose another admin calls the same function for the same user, next letter will be issued by two admins. I want to prevent this."* What do you want to happen? Do you want the second admin's attempt to fail with an error, do you want the second admin's attempt to wait and retry, do you want something else? (Database transaction isolation levels can control this kind of thing.)

Comment: Second admin's attempt should wait and retry. Because both are allowed to issue notices, but only seuentially

Answer (score 0):

This is a great case scenario for the transaction pattern.

Here is a good read about it: https://blog.matthewskelton.net/2005/08/22/better-transactions-with-delegates-in-csharp/

As a possible solution you might want to have the data update inside a transaction that can be accessed only by one admin at the time.

Comment: If both admins are calling the functions with seperate user ids, they should be allowed. I suppose "a transaction that can be accessed only by one admin at the time." will not allow this.